# Template branching with respect to a specific interface type

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to distinguish when a template type implements a given interface. I thought I could achieve this by using a generic template method and its specialization for the interface type interested in. If I the method is call with a type that implements that specific interface, the compiler will resolve it with a call to the specialize method. Otherwise, it will call the generic method. For example, I summarize this idea in in the following code snippet :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Info {
  virtual std::string whoAmI() = 0;
};

struct Person: Info {
  std::string whoAmI() { return "Person"; }
};

template<typename T>
bool is_info(const T &)
{
  return false;
}

template<>
bool is_info(const Info& )
{
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << is_info(1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << is_info(Person()) << std::endl;
}
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work. `is_info(Person())` returns 0, when it should return 1. Why? How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: Instead of specializing just make a normal overload for `bool is_info(const Info&) { return true; }`.

Comment: @JamesAdkison the function template produces an exact match, so no

Comment: How about `template <typename T> constexpr bool is_info(const T &) { return std::is_base_of<Info, T>::value; }` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, my mistake. That's because it's being called with a derived type and the overload is defined using the base type, correct?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki using `is_base_of` to call the correct function should  work. The only problem I have is that I cannot use C++11 yet :( I hope to find it in the boost version I am using

Comment: If you cannot use C++11, why did you add a c++11 tag to the question?

Comment: Can you elaborate on which compiler and flags you're using?

What happens if you specialize a struct template instead of a function template, as in this example: http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442?

Comment: @jotik You're right. However, I left it in because I think it is useful to see the asnwer for both c++11 and boost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `std::is_base_of` like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_info(T const &)
{ return std::is_base_of<Info, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value; }
```

This also works with `boost::is_base_of` and `boost::decay` in pre-C++11:

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template <typename T>
bool is_info(T const &)
{ return boost::is_base_of<Info, typename boost::decay<T>::type>::value; }
```